# ScrollTop on mobile device

Tags: jquery, ios, css, scroll, viewport

I am trying to make a site which should also be accessible on mobile devices.
Since iOS 7 is coming out, i wanted to recreate the depth and blurry look.
I did this with using a iframe and putting a css3 filter on it, i make the
iframe scroll the same as the page with jquery. On the computer it looks fine
but when i'm on a mobile device (iPhone iOS 6 with safari) the iframe only scrolls
when i'm done scrolling. Is there anyway i could make it move when i'm scrolling
not just when i'm done?

this is the code i'm using:

```
   $(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var t = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#blur').contents().find('body').scrollTop(t);
  });
});
```

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5ZbH/.

Thanks,

Comment: why are you using a bunch of iframes instead of just divs?

Comment: i couldn't think of any other method to blur everything behind the div.

Comment: @joeyjansen: just wrap everything in your div and apply at that div your css3 blur filter

Answer (score 0):

Actually, some of the mobile handheld devices are still not supporting position:fixed; properly. In some of the devices, this is being supported partially. When the complete scroll is done, that resets the position and in mid-way of scroll, that goes with the page scroll flow. So, yeah... this is a bug as of now in the phones and tablets.

I am happy that android are good in this. :)